# Is there any way to perform Integration testing on API rate limiting?

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing, xunit, rate-limiting

I have been trying to add Integration testing for API rate limiting. I am using Xunit with Asp.NetCore.

Right now, I have rate limited my api calls to **x calls per minute**. In my Integration test, I try to run **x+1 number** of api calls and check for **429 error status code**. However, I see that my INT test waits for a minute and **retry the (x+1)th** call and report it as success. (I use Fiddler to check this)

```
public async Task GetRateLimited()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        var response = await client.GetApi();
    }
    Func<Task> action = async () => await client.GetApi();
    MyException exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<MyException>(action);
    exception.Response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);
}
```

Is there any way to check for the HttpStatusCode 429 requests?

Thanks,

Manisha

Comment: Can you edit your post to share a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) excerpt of your test code?

Comment: something like this: 
 ``       public async Task GetRateLimited()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                var response = await client.GetApi();

            }

            Func<Task> action = async () => await client.GetApi();

            MyException exception = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<MyException>(action);
            exception.Response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests);
        }``

Comment: Okay, but please edit your post to include this code, and use proper [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) when you do so.